# How do I reload the page AND jump to an anchor?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to refresh a page when it gets a message from a service worker, which happens when there is new content to be seen (which is what the anchor should be jumping to when the page is refreshed).

So imagine I have these:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/home.htm';
var anchor = '#comment-45';
```

and the page with that url is already loaded. I want to reload the page, and jump to #comment-45.

**All of these don't work:**

This doesn't reload the page, just tries to jump to the nonexistant anchor:

```
 window.location = url+anchor;
```

Changes to correct URL and reloads, but doesn't jump to new anchor:

```
    window.location.hash = anchor;
    window.location.reload(true);
```

OR

```
    window.location.href = url+anchor;
    window.location.reload(true);
```

Reloads the page to the base URL, but doesn't change the anchor:

```
    window.location = url;
    window.location.hash = anchor;
```

Comment: When you reload a page the browser remembers where you were scrolled to. This is normal behavior, and I would recommend against hacking around it. When you first load a page it is fine to set scroll to anchor, though.

Comment: Well I want to scroll to the new content. But it doesn't exist until after the page is reloaded.

Comment: Ok, then I think it was a good idea to go to a new url, though I see you already tried a few ways of doing that that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you add

```
<a id="comment-45">Comment 45</a>
```

you can have this in the bottom of the page before the `</body>`

```
<script>
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a[id]");
const lastLink = links[links.length-1];
if (lastLink) {
  window.location.hash = lastLink.id; // for bookmarking
  lastLink.scrollIntoView(); 
}
</script>
```

and then a

```
window.location.reload(1);
```

will scroll to whatever is the last anchor at reload time

Answer (score 2):

In my experience there are a number of situations that won't trigger the browser to scroll to the anchor. I've found a fallback that looks for a hash/fragment in the URL and scrolls to it on load using JS to be more reliable. If you can add the anchor and reload with one of the approaches you outlined, you should be able to use this to handle the scrolling:

```js
const scrollTo = el => {
  if (el) {
    const top = window.scrollY + el.getBoundingClientRect().top
    window.scrollTo({ top: top, behavior: "smooth" })
  }
}

// wrap in a domReady type callback if needed
scrollTo(document.querySelector(window.location.hash))
```